# Finding the possibilities of the 4th vertices of a parallelogram

Tags: vectors

The points (1, -2, 4), (3, 5, 7) and (4, 6, 8) are three of four vertices of parallelogram ABCD. Explain why there are three possibilities for the location of the fourth vertex, and find the three points.

I have found one possibility that is (2,-1,5) but I'm not sure how any other possibilities could exist.

Comment: To get some intuition for this problem, plot three random points in a plane. Draw out the three possible parallelograms.

Answer (score 1):

$\bf hint:$ you have three pairs of possible opposite vertices call them $a,c$ and the third one $b.$ the fourth vertex is $a+c - b.$

Answer (score 0):

Divide a parallelogram in two by drawing one of its two diagonals. Can you not see that the now-missing vertex, except for fickle fate, might have been constructed, with equal validity, on any side of the remaining triangle?

Answer (score 0):

out of the three points, any pair (say A and B) could be the diagonally opposite corners with lines connected to the 3rd point (C) but not to each other. then C is diagonally opposite to the point you need to find, D. since C could be any one of the 3 different points that you know, D could be any of 3 points diagonally opposite to C. I have not calculated the coordinates of D, but 3 exist.